# How to efficiently split a big data.table into two according to a rule that involves 2 columns?

Tags: r, split, data.table

What is the most efficient (time and space alike) way to split the following table

```
dt = data.table(x=c(1,3,5,4,6,2), y=c(4,7,1,1,2,6))
> dt
   x y
1: 1 4
2: 3 7
3: 5 1
4: 4 1
5: 6 2
6: 2 6
```

into two separate tables, dt1, and dt2, such that dt1 contains all (x,y) rows iff (y,x) is also a row in dt, while dt2 contains the other rows:

```
> dt1
   x y
1: 1 4
2: 4 1
3: 6 2
4: 2 6

> dt2
   x y
1: 3 7
2: 5 1
```

Efficiency is critical, the full table has nearly 200M rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to perform a backward join to itself

```
indx <- sort.int(dt[unique(dt), on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L])

dt[indx]
#    x y
# 1: 1 4
# 2: 4 1
# 3: 6 2
# 4: 2 6

dt[-indx]
#    x y
# 1: 3 7
# 2: 5 1
```

**Benchmark** - If you don't care about the order, my solution seem to be faster for a 200MM rows (both solutions result unordered)

```
set.seed(123)
bigdt <- data.table(x = sample(1e3, 2e8, replace = TRUE),
                    y = sample(1e3, 2e8, replace = TRUE))

system.time(i1 <- bigdt[, .I[.N>1] ,.(X=pmax(x,y), Y=pmin(y,x))]$V1)
# user  system elapsed 
# 21.81    0.82   22.97 

system.time(indx <- bigdt[unique(bigdt), on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 17.74    0.90   18.80 

# Checking if both unsorted and if identical when sorted
is.unsorted(i1)
# [1] TRUE
is.unsorted(indx)
# [1] TRUE

identical(sort.int(i1), sort.int(indx))
# [1] TRUE
```

And here is a nondegenerate case (where `indx != bigdt[, .I]`):

```
set.seed(123)
n  = 1e7
nv = 1e4
DT <- data.table(x = sample(nv, n, replace = TRUE), y = sample(nv, n, replace = TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  akrun  = {
    idx = DT[, .I[.N > 1], by=.(pmax(x,y), pmin(x,y))]$V1
    list(DT[idx], DT[-idx])
  },
  akrun2 = {
    idx = DT[,{
      x1 <- paste(pmin(x,y), pmax(x,y))
      duplicated(x1)|duplicated(x1, fromLast=TRUE)
    }]
    list(DT[idx], DT[!idx])
  },
  davida = {
    idx = DT[unique(DT), on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
    list(DT[idx], DT[-idx])
  },
  akrun3 = {
    n = DT[, N := .N, by = .(pmax(x,y), pmin(x,y))]$N
    DT[, N := NULL]
    split(DT, n > 1L)
  }, times = 1)

Unit: seconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  akrun  7.056609  7.056609  7.056609  7.056609  7.056609  7.056609     1
 akrun2 22.810844 22.810844 22.810844 22.810844 22.810844 22.810844     1
 davida  2.738918  2.738918  2.738918  2.738918  2.738918  2.738918     1
 akrun3  5.662700  5.662700  5.662700  5.662700  5.662700  5.662700     1
```

Comment: I think you should test with an example that does not have `identical(sort(indx), bigdt[, .I]) # TRUE`

Comment: I have one, will edit in. Yours turns out to win in my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot David.
Just on a side note (which isn't the case I'm interested in), arkun's solution is extendable to triplets (or tuples in general), rather than pairs. Just switch pmin(),pmax() with sort(). Your solution demands that in the on = c() phase I stick to only one possible permutation of the values in each row.

Comment: @Amitai what do you mean by "*Just switch pmin(),pmax() with sort()*"? Do you mean to sort by row? This will be a super slow operation for a big data set in such case.

Comment: @Amitai I guess the extension would involve the `melt` function. Generally, you shouldn't store a matrix as columns in a data.table, if that's what you have in mind.

Comment: get the indices from the opposite merge, and you won't need to sort or unique (and will thus be a little faster); also the code will be cleaner. I.e. do `idx = DT[!DT, on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = T]`

Comment: actually you might still want to unique-ify - depends on data

Answer (score 4):

We could try

```
i1 <- dt[, .I[.N>1] ,.(X=pmax(x,y), Y=pmin(y,x))]$V1
dt[i1]
#   x y
#1: 1 4
#2: 4 1
#3: 6 2
#4: 2 6

dt[-i1]
#   x y
#1: 3 7
#2: 5 1
```

---

Or another option using `duplicated`

```
 i1 <-  dt[,{x1 <- paste(pmin(x,y), pmax(x,y))
         duplicated(x1)|duplicated(x1, fromLast=TRUE) }]
 dt[i1]
 dt[!i1]
```

Comment: Brilliant!
Although I'll go with David Arenburg solution due to slightly better performance (my data-set has unique rows so I spare even the unique() phase), what I like about this solution is that it is extendable to triplets and tuples in general. Just switch the pmin(),pmax() into sorted row!

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow @David Arenburg and @akrun answers (definitely not trying to post a new one, this is just to long for a comment), I have timed also functions with sorting:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
bigdt <- data.table(x = sample(1e3, 2e8, replace = TRUE),
                    y = sample(1e3, 2e8, replace = TRUE))

f1 <- function() bigdt[, .I[.N>1] ,.(X=pmax(x,y), Y=pmin(y,x))]$V1
f2 <- function() bigdt[, .I[.N>1] ,.(X=pmax(x,y), Y=pmin(y,x))] %>% setorder(V1) %>% .[, V1]
f3 <- function() bigdt[unique(bigdt), on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
f4 <- function() sort.int(bigdt[unique(bigdt), on = c(x = "y", y = "x"), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L])

res <- microbenchmark(
    i1 <- f1(),
    i2 <- f2(),
    i3 <- f3(),
    i4 <- f4(),
    times = 2L)

print(res)
```

With:

```
is.unsorted(i1)  # TRUE
is.unsorted(i2)  # FALSE
is.unsorted(i3)  # TRUE
is.unsorted(i4)  # FALSE

identical(sort.int(i1), i2)  # TRUE
identical(sort.int(i3), i4)  # TRUE
identical(i2, i4)            # TRUE
```

And the results are as follow:

```
Unit: seconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 i1 <- f1() 21.18695 21.18695 21.42634 21.42634 21.66572 21.66572     2 a  
 i2 <- f2() 47.16270 47.16270 47.79535 47.79535 48.42799 48.42799     2  b 
 i3 <- f3() 19.67623 19.67623 20.11365 20.11365 20.55108 20.55108     2 a  
 i4 <- f4() 57.21732 57.21732 57.78666 57.78666 58.35600 58.35600     2   c
```

**Summing up**:

- `f3()` is falser for unsorted result;
- `f2()` is faster when sorting is counted in.